# Accessing feature attachments using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, features, attachments

I am attempting to access a feature's attachments in ArcObjects and I'm following the docs for [Working with feature attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001qr000000.htm).  Everything is fine until attempt to access IAttachment.Data because I am expecting there to be data, but that property is null:

[image]

which means I can't proceed past:
`IMemoryBlobStream memoryBlobStream = attachment.Data;`

I am thinking there is a missing step (or steps) in the docs that would fill the attachment object's `Data` property with actual data? How is this done?

I am able to access the attachment via the Identify window within ArcMap, so I know the data is there:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a combination of me copying the wrong snippet of code and not fully reading the docs that I had referenced in my question!

> The Boolean parameter ("Info Only") of these methods determines which
>   properties of the returned attachments will be populated.

I had copied:

`IEnumAttachment enumAttachment = attachmentManager.GetAttachmentsByParentIDs (parentIdArray, true);`

Changing it to false brings brings back the `.Data` value:

`IEnumAttachment enumAttachment = attachmentManager.GetAttachmentsByParentIDs (parentIdArray, false);`

Both lines of code are present in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I have never done this using the .NET SDK, but I have used this python script in the past:

```py
import arcpy, os, sys
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def extract_attachments(out_ws, table, blob_field, filename_fld):
    '''
    Code adopted from "Another GIS Blog"
        http://anothergisblog.blogspot.nl/2012/06/working-with-blob-data-at-101-arcpyda.html

    """ Exports all attachments from a geodatabase to a new location """

    Required:
    out_ws -- location for attachments
    table -- table or feature class containing attachment info
    blob_field -- field containing attachment files
    filename_fld -- field name containing file name
    '''

    # make sure out_ws exists, if not create
    if not os.path.exists(out_ws):
        os.makedirs(out_ws)

    # search cursor
    c = 0
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ['REL_OBJECTID', blob_field, filename_fld]) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            roid, binRep, fileName = row
            if binRep:
                out_file = os.path.join(out_ws, 'OID_' + '_'.join(map(str, [roid, fileName])))
                open(out_file, 'wb').write(binRep.tobytes())
                c += 1

    arcpy.AddMessage('Exported {0} attachments to: "{1}"'.format(c, out_ws))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # run as script tool
    extract_attachments(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Does this have to be done in ArcObjects?